# Setting Presentation Aliases with Sitecore Powershell Extensions

Tags: powershell-extensions

In Sitecore 9, in the Content Editor and under the Presentation tab, there's an option to set Aliases on an item. Assuming you already have the desired item stored in variable $item, how would you set a new alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an alias, you just need to create an item under `/sitecore/system/aliases` using the template `/sitecore/templates/System/Alias` and fill in the required fields.

In SPE that would look something like

```
$aliasName = "Your Alias Name Here"
$newAlias = New-Item -Path "master:\system\aliases" -Name $aliasName -ItemType "system/alias"
$newAlias.Editing.BeginEdit()
$newAlias._."Linked Item".TargetID = $item.ID
$newAlias._."Linked Item".LinkType = "internal"
$newAlias.Editing.EndEdit();
```

That will create the alias item and set the linked item to the item in your `$item` variable.

The alias url is defined by the item name of the alias item. So you would need to set that to whatever you wanted the alias to be. Maybe with a `Read-Variable` to get the user input.